# Counting unique features of points inside polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

I have a series of points with various fields in the attribute table, including a `car_id`. I also have several polygons in which some of these points are located.

[image]

I want to count how many unique `car_id`'s occur in each polygon. For example, if there are multiple points in a polygon where `car_id = 25`, the `car_id = 25` should be counted once. The `car_id` count for a polygon using the sample data below should be 4.

```
car_id = 25
car_id = 25
car_id = 25
car_id = 22
car_id = 22
car_id = 23
car_id = 24
```

What is the best approach to achieve this? Or is there an appropriate QGIS tool available in QGIS 3 to do this?

I know that in QGIS 2.x the tool 'Count Unique Points In Polygon' would have worked. However this tool is not available anymore in QGIS 3.10.

Comment: have you had a look at `v.vect.stats` and `count points in polygon`? If so, how do they not suit your needs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Count Points In Polygon** tool in QGIS 3 counts the unique values, too. But first you have to select 'Class Field' parameter which is used to specify a unique field name.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can run a SQL query in QGIS/database/DB Manager, something like the following :

```
SELECT polygon_id, COUNT (DISTINCT car_id) FROM point_layer, polygon_layer
where st_intersects(point.geometry, polygon.geometry)
group by polygon_id
```